What shapes can roll down tailor-made curves?
Background
It is well-known that the disk can roll down various curves, including the straight line and the Brachistochrone curve. The latter is the curve along which both a point rolls down the fastest. The disk rolls fastest along a modified version of the Brachistochrone. Various variations and generalizations of this problem have been described here, for instance.
What I am interested in, are different types of shapes that roll down various curves. For instance, I wonder along what curve the ellipse rolls down the fastest. It turns out that this is a difficult problem. In fact, it may even be the case that the ellipse cannot roll down any curve without eventually jumping and moving chaotically.
In a series of videos by Morphocular, it is described how to find the curve along which any two-dimensional shape can roll along horizontally in a smooth manner. These curves are called roulettes. In case of the ellipse, it turns out that its roulette is a sine curve. One can find a suitable curve for horizontal motion for any shape. Below, I depict three examples (this is a still from one of the videos by Morphocular).

Question
However, I don't know yet which shapes can roll down, without jumping off at some point. For instance, one could try to roll a square down a parabola. However, it will quickly lose contact with the parabola, and start behaving chaotically. Even in the combinations of the shapes and curves depicted above, the roulettes, the shapes can probably only roll along the curve horizontally. But if we tried tilting the curves so the shapes roll down, they probably jump off at some point.
Of course, one can consider modifications of a circle to think of 'new' shapes that can roll down various curves. For instance, if one makes a circular hole in the center of the circle (so one effectively obtains an annulus), then this different shape can roll down as well.
What I find more interesting, are shapes that actually have a different outside boundary. So my question is:

What shapes can roll down a tailor-made curve without jumping off and behaving chaotically, and how does one mathematically describe these curves? How do these curves relate to the shape?

Note: this may be a relevant question.

If it's decreasing everywhere, I think most "nice enough" (convex?) shapes will roll down.

@VarunVejalla Could you elaborate on what you mean by "If it's decreasing everywhere..." ? What is 'it' in this case?

Sorry, I meant the curve, at least if you could interpret it as a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

@VarunVejalla I see. And how will convexity help the shapes to roll down? Take, for instance, the regular pentagon, which is convex. I don't believe it will roll down smoothly along a parabola or a brachistochrone, for instance. Even the curve described by Morphocular (in the picture) may not allow it to roll down without jumping off -- this will require a proof.
